# Is there a way to make RichEmbed methods work in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js

When attempting to use this code I got the error below:

```js
const embed = new RichEmbed();

var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let name = part + num + ".gif";

embed.attachFiles([name]);
embed.setImage('attachment://' + name);

mess.channel.send(embed);
```

```
TypeError: embed.attachFiles is not a function
```

I if I delete away `embed.attachFiles([name])` I get an error saying that `embed.setImage` isn't a function either.
Is there anything I can do to make Heroku register these as functions? It is worth noting that **this worked outside of Heroku**, when I ran it using the command line on my own computer.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku by itself does not modify the behavior of discord.js. Here's a list of things you can try:

- Verify that your `package.json` file is updated with the version of discord.js you want and run `npm i` to make sure the version on your pc is the same*.
- Make sure that `RichEmbed` is `Discord.RichEmbed`: try to write it explicitly to see if that helps.
- Try to `console.log(embed)` and see what gets logged in the console: that might give you a clue of what the problem is...

* The [`RichEmbed.attachFile()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=attachFile) method was added in the [11.0.0 version](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.0.0/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=attachFile): any previous version of discord.js won't allow you to use it.

Comment: I changed the version of discord.js to what is running on my computer, and it is giving me new errors now:
```npm ERR! code ETARGET
       npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for discord.js@6.4.1
       npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
       npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
       npm ERR! notarget 
       npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'Trojinator'
       npm ERR! notarget ```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to install the 6.4.1 version: that's way too old, there's no way your code could have worked with that version. Try to `npm i discord.js@11.4.2`